# Python 3 - alignment and spacing

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to create a new text file using information from another text file.
i.e.

```
john doe, 88, uk
mike green, 212, usa
```

I want it to look like :

```
name                         number                               country
```

(left justified and specific width)

i am trying to align it left and create specific spacing between the columns.

i have serach this and cannot find a solution, the closest syntax is below:

```
lines = old_file.readlines()
print ("{0:<25} {1:<6} {2:<35}".format(*lines)
```

the above code does not work and I am not sure how to refer to the values from another text file - after the .format syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to split the lines and to loop over each one:

```
lines = old_file.readlines()
for l in lines:
    print('{0:<25} {1:<6} {2:<35}'.format(*l.split(',')))
```

```
john doe                   88     uk                                
mike green                 212    usa
```